# Feature request: We have the notation already. Can we make it easier to access and how can we hear it played (synthesized not recorded)?

Tags: feature-request

The abcjs and jTab extensions seem to work well enough *when they're used*.

Two thoughts on improving them, based on my experience with the online schematic editor linked to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/:

1. Can we include a toolbar button to insert them (for abcjs, it could insert the minimum header content automatically).  Here's the toolbar from ee.se:

[image: Toolbar]

2. Can we somehow integrate a way to play abcjs and jTab notation through the browser?  On ee.se, circuits made with the integrated editor can be simulated right from a link in SE:
   [image: Simulator link]